# delete data from database using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I have database that consists 4 tables (Players, Achievements, Matches, Tournaments). Data is displaying using JTable. I want to delete data from table when I click Delete button. The problem is I don't know the name of table which user want's to modify so I can't write correct SQL statement

`PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("delete * from ?");`

How can I get table name?

GUI:

```
public class FbGui {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FbGui window = new FbGui();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public FbGui() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    Connection con = null;

    private void initialize() {
        con = FbConnect.dbConnector();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 642, 422);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(189, 39, 427, 120);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JButton btnShowPlayers = new JButton("Show players");
        btnShowPlayers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {
                    PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("select * from fbdb.players");
                    ResultSet rs=pstm.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));

                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnShowPlayers.setBounds(31, 36, 148, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnShowPlayers);

        JButton btnShowAchievements = new JButton("Show achievements");
        btnShowAchievements.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("select * from fbdb.achievements");
                    ResultSet rs=pstm.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));

                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnShowAchievements.setBounds(31, 70, 148, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnShowAchievements);


        JButton btnShowTournaments = new JButton("Show tournaments");
        btnShowTournaments.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("select * from fbdb.tournaments");
                    ResultSet rs=pstm.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));

                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnShowTournaments.setBounds(31, 104, 148, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnShowTournaments);

        JButton btnShowMatches = new JButton("Show matches");
        btnShowMatches.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("select * from fbdb.matches");
                    ResultSet rs=pstm.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));

                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnShowMatches.setBounds(31, 136, 148, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnShowMatches);



        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("delete * from ?");
                    pstm.execute();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnDelete.setBounds(208, 181, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDelete);
    }

    public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
            throws SQLException {

        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        // names of columns
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }

        // data of the table
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }

        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. You *have* the table names, as you're querying them in your code. Do you want do delete all four of the tables? Or do you want the user to pick a specific table to delete?

Comment: @CraigOtis specific table

Comment: You can use a var to store which kind of data is shown in your JTable. And in your delete statement you can test this var to know what table you have to query.

Comment: What about a dropdown menu next to your Delete button?

Comment: What I understood from the code : one jtable, many buttons "show players", "show matches" (...) which feed the same jtable. And a single button to delete. The problem is that rokky never stores which kind of data is shown in the jtable.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:
Take a temporary variable as

```
String whichTable="";
```

and when you click on button store name of table in this variable e.g.

```
btnShowPlayers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {
                    PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("select * from fbdb.players");
                    ResultSet rs=pstm.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));        
                    whichTable="fbdb.player;";//do this.


                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Do same for other button actions
and in your delete button action use this whichTable variable. e.g.:

```
JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("delete * from "+whichTable);//put where condition also if required .
                    pstm.execute();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: I've done this, but it gives the exception: "You have an error in your SQL syntax" :(

Comment: if you wish to delete all records then just write like this: " delete from table_name "

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a question mark as placeholder for the table name in a PreparedStatement. You'll need to use a normal statement e.g.:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.execute("delete from "+tableName);
```

Comment: The question was : "How can I get table name?"